# AngularJS Routing for Master Page or Index page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I would like to associate angularJs controller for the index page(which acts as the master page. Here I m using ASP.NET MVC for referring to the template URL. Hence it refers to MVC controller method rather than the actual html file.

```
myapp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {



    $routeProvider.when('/',
{
    templateUrl: '/',
    controller: 'IndexController'
});
    $routeProvider.when('/First',
  {
      templateUrl: '/Angular/FirstChild',
      controller: 'ChildController'
  });
```

The routing for page "First" works fine and child controller triggers fine but the index page causing problem, it repeatedly calls itself and then page starts to display Index Index Index .... in the new line continuously and page becomes unresponsive..

Can anyone help me to understand this.. Again want to insist that problem comes in, when I want to associate controller with index page, if I navigate from my index page to page "first", "Second" and so on, I m not getting any issues

Comment: shouldn't templateUrl give back a HTML template, e.g. ``'index.html'``?

Comment: here it refers to cshtml page which will be rendered by ASP.NET MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

Angular routing doesn't really work like this. The routing is designed to load various HTML templates into the view without ever refreshing the page, which makes it a single page in essence, these templates really don't have anything to do with asp out of the box. I'm sure you've looked at Angular's docs, but here's a good tutorial on how to properly using NgRoute: [Scotch Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

A way you can connect a controller to any of your ASP pages (as long as your are hooking your angular scripts into the page) is by using the `ng-controller="myController"` attribute on the parent element you wish to use angular with.